# json proper encoding and decoding not working with flask, python

Tags: python-2.7, flask, json

I'm taking a text-input from html being json object and trying to work upon that. But when I'm trying the following code, I'm getting error/(page not rendering) in encoding and decoding `JSON`.

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def my_form_post():

    text = request.form['text']
    #getting text-input as text = {'a':'1','b':'2'}

    json_input = json.dumps(text)
    ordered_json = json.loads(text, object_pairs_hook=ordereddict.OrderedDict)
    print ordered_json
    processed_text = htmlConvertor(ordered_json)
    #rep(jso)
    return render_template("my-form.html",processed_text=processed_text)
```

But when I'm tying to do so with a local `JSON` variable as `jso` everything working fine. The same input when I provide with html-input, it's giving an error and I can;t even see the error except displaying **Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.**

```
 @app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
        def my_form_post():

            jso = '''{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'''

        json_input = json.dumps(jso)
        ordered_json = json.loads(jso, object_pairs_hook=ordereddict.OrderedDict)
        print ordered_json
        processed_text = htmlConvertor(ordered_json)
        #rep(jso)
        return render_template("my-form.html",processed_text=processed_text)
```

**UPDATE:**

Everything working fine now, but for the integers, it isn't working.
For eg:

```
{"name":"yo","price":"250"}
```

works perfectly but

```
{"name":"yo","price":250}
```

ain't.
What's the solution for that? Any specific answer or I would have to check for `integer` in python and then convert it to string before applying any `JSON` related methods and functioning.

Comment: please add the full traceback you get in console

Comment: @PaoloCasciello: I didn't get any traceback since my debug mode wasn't ON and yes, turning it on and using double quotes solves my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is your problem, but `{'a':'1','b':'2'}` is not a valid JSON object because of the single quotes:

```
>>> json.loads("{'a':'1','b':'2'}")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/__init__.py", line 307, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/decoder.py", line 319, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/decoder.py", line 336, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self._scanner.iterscan(s, **kw).next()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/scanner.py", line 55, in iterscan
    rval, next_pos = action(m, context)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/decoder.py", line 171, in JSONObject
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Expecting property name", s, end))
ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 1 (char 1)
```

If instead you use double quotes everything works fine:

```
>>> json.loads("{\"a\":\"1\",\"b\":\"2\"}")
{u'a': u'1', u'b': u'2'}
```

Also note that to get stack traces intead of code 500 errors when there is an exception you have to start your flask server as follows:

```
app.run(debug = True)
```

Comment: `app.run(debug = True)` gives me the full insight and yep, double quotes solve the whole problem. Thanks for pointing that out